# Storing multiple foreign keys of the same type in Entity Framework but only one needs a foreign key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In an MVC Project, I have a Page class and a Container class. I'm intending for each to have their own table in the database, so for each page, there will be a list of containers to choose from. A Page can have multiple containers and a single container can be used on multiple pages.

My problem is, I don't want anything to be stored in the Container class regarding the page it is on. A Page contains the the Containers but from the Container class, the page is is found on is irrelevant.

All of the Entity Framework examples I have seen for this type of relationship seem to store a foreign key on both classes.

```
    public class Page
    {
          public int Id { get; set; }
          public virtual ICollection<Container> Containers {get;set;} 
          ...
     }
     public class Container
     {
          public int Id { get; set; }
          public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages{get;set;} 
          ...
     }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck trying to find the correct way to do this for a few days.

Thanks.

Comment: It is just a many-to-many realtionship so a join table will be create that will store the foreign keys;

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want anything to be stored in the Container class regarding the page it 
>   is on.

This is simply a difference between OO modeling and relational modeling.  In a pure OO model you can have a property of type

```
class Foo
{
    List<Bar> Bars = new List<Bar>();
}
```

And the Bar objects don't have any knowledge about the Foo object.  But the relational model simply doesn't work like that.  Relationships are all implemented with foreign keys.  So in the database foreign keys are required.  And while EF supports having an entity without a foreign key property, it's discouraged.

However in your case this is a Many-to-Many relationship.  And in the relational model that uses a linking table, and the foreign key columns are on the linking table, not on the entity tables.  The only thing on the entity is a Navigation Property, which is not structural, and can be omitted.  You just need to tell EF the cardinality of the relationship, since in your current model the relationship is defined by convention based on the Navigation Properties.

So something like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ef6test
{
    public class Page
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Container> Containers { get; set; } 

     }
    public class Container
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
       // public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; } 

     }

    public class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Container> Containers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<Page>()
                        .HasMany(p => p.Containers)
                        .WithMany();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.Create();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

David